# Objective-c class create methods

Tags: objective-c

Let's say we have a class Base.

```
@inerface Base : NSObject
{
}
+(id) instance;
@end

@implementation Base
+(id) instance
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
-(id) init
{
...
}
@end
```

And we have a derived class Derived.

```
@interface Derived : Base
{
}
@end
```

Which reimplements the `init` method.

Now we want to create an instance of Derived class using class method `+(id) instance`.

```
id foo = [Derived instance];
```

And now foo is actually a Base class.

How to achieve foo to be a Derived class in this case?

Should I reimplement all the class method for derived classes ? (actually immplementation will be totally the same).

Is there a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an instance using `[Derived instance]`, that instance will be of class `Derived`. Try it. The trick is messaging `self` in the `instance` method:

```
+(id) instance
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

When you send the `instance` message to `Base`, `self` is `Base`. When you send the same message to `Derived`, `self` is `Derived` and therefore the whole thing works as desirable.

Comment: Damn, i've written return [[[Base alloc] init] autorelease]; in instance method in my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain how can i use self word in a class method. What does it mean?

Comment: “Within the [method] implementation, both `self` and `super` refer to the receiving object,” see [Language Summary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocLanguageSummary.html) in the Objective-C book by Apple.